# How to make node movable in y-axis in the hierarchical layout in visjs?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Whenever i use the hierarchical layout for layouting nodes, it is possible to move with them only in x-axis. I would like to have nodes movable in all directions.

Comment: If you could move them in both axis it would no-longer be a hierarchical layout. If you don't want to constrain one axis you should just use the default layout.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to display the graph in the hierarchical order (or layout if you want), but after layouting (and stabilization, etc..) be able to move with nodes in all directions (give the user freedom to manipulate later).

Comment: I believe it is possible to specify the initial position of each node explicitly on when you load the network. I could imagine a solution where you create the network in hierarchical mode, then once it has settled programmatically get the x,y position of each node then reload the network in standard mode with using the explicit positions you calculated earlier.

Comment: I used your idea with a little modification, but it works ;) Still think, that it should be done with less work (i don't understand, why y-axis is fixed and can't be switched to be movable). But thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with little effort.

```
const options = {
    nodes: { borderWidth: 2 },
    edges: {length: 300, smooth: false },
    physics: {
        enabled: false
        },
    layout:{
        improvedLayout: true,
        hierarchical: {
            levelSeparation:200, 
            nodeSpacing: 200, 
            treeSpacing:200, 
            }
        },
    interaction: { hover: true }
   }
const network = new vis.Network(container, visData, options);
setTimeout(()=>{
    network.setOptions({
        layout:{
            hierarchical: false
        },
    });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to turn off hierarchical layout after the diagram has rendered once, then stop any further simulation.

```
 var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

 network.on("stabilized", function () {
   network.stopSimulation();
   network.setOptions({
    "layout": {"hierarchical": {"enabled": false}},                  
    });
  });

  var hasDrawnOnce = false;
  network.on("startStabilizing", function() {
    if(hasDrawnOnce!=false){
      network.stopSimulation(); 
    }
    hasDrawnOnce=true;
  });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but the one above did. I feel like your's should work though! I probably just set it up wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you can move most of nodes in both axis even in hierarchical layout, if you make some nodes fixed (which cannot be moved in any axis).
Try adding `{ fixed: True }` to one node, and try moving rest of them.